# Functions that can be expanded in group representation theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm a physics student and I don't have a strong background of algebra, so please excuse me if I made some mistakes.

I read it [here on the top of page 96](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.734j/www/group-full02.pdf) that:

> Any arbitrary function $F$ can be written as a linear combination of a complete set of basis functions $f^{\Gamma_{n'}}_{j'}$
>   $F= \sum_{n'}\sum_{j'} f^{\Gamma_{n'}}_{j'} |\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$

in which $|\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$ represents the $j' -th$ basis function of the $n' -th$ irreducible representation of some arbitrary finite group.

**The thing confuses me is that are there any restrictions on the function $F$?**

For finite groups, both the number of invariant spaces and the dimension of each invariant space are finite, so that we have a finite set of basis functions of a finite group. (the set of functions of $|\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$)

Let's say the set of basis functions is $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$ for some finite group. Clearly, there are a lot of functions that can not be expanded by this basis.

Comment: I assume you mean functions on a finite group? In that case there are no restrictions, assuming I've understood what "basis function" means here.

Answer (score 2):

For any function $F:F(g) \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \mathrm{~or~} \mathbb{R} $ defined on a finite group $G=\{g_1, g_2, ... , g_N\}$, we can regard it as a column vector.

$$
  \begin{align}
    F(G) &= \begin{bmatrix}
           F(g_1) \\
           F(g_2) \\
           \vdots \\
           F(g_N)
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
$$
, where $F(g)$ is a number.

Since $F(g)$ is arbitrary function,the dimension of this column vector is $|G| = N$.

Now, from the group orthogonality theorem, we have

$$
\sum_{g} D_{ij}^{\alpha}(g)^ * D_{kl}^{\beta}(g) = \frac{|G|}{d_{\alpha}} \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl}
$$

Here, you can think that each $D_{ij}^{\alpha}$ is a group function since it assigns a number for each group element.

$$
  \begin{align}
    D_{ij}^{\alpha}(G) &= \begin{bmatrix}
           D_{ij}^{\alpha}(g_1) \\
           D_{ij}^{\alpha}(g_2) \\
           \vdots \\
           D_{ij}^{\alpha}(g_N)
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
$$

Now if you regard $D_{ij}^{\alpha}$ as a column vector in the $|G|$ dimensional vector space, group orthogonality says that the vector $D_{ij}^{\alpha}$ and $D_{kl}^{\beta}$ are orthoggonal.

$$
\langle D_{ij}^{\alpha} | D_{kl}^{\beta} \rangle = \sum_{g} D_{ij}^{\alpha}(g)^ * D_{kl}^{\beta}(g) =  0
$$
, if $(\alpha, i, j) \neq (\beta, k, l)$. Then, how many orthogonal vectors do we have? From the dimensionality theorem about group representation, we know

$$
\sum_\alpha d_{\alpha} ^2 = |G|
$$

, thus we have |G| ortthogonal column vectors $D_{ij}^{\alpha}$ (each representation $D^{\alpha}$ is $d_{\alpha}$ dimensional matrix, so you have $d_{\alpha}^2$ group functions for each representation). Since we have |G| orthogonal vectors (so linearly independent), they can span arbitrary $F(G)$ in |G| dimension.